# How to play part of wav file by Naudio/c#

Tags: c#, playback, naudio

I would like to play some part of wave file, e.g. from 20 to 50 second. I'm using Naudio in my C# project.  I know how to start at 20 second:

```
private NAudio.Wave.AudioFileReader wave = null;
private NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut outputSound = null;
...
timeFrom = 20;
wave = new NAudio.Wave.AudioFileReader(file);
wave.Position += (long)((double)wave.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond * timeFrom);
outputSound = new NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut();
outputSound.Init(new NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32(wave));
outputSound.Play();
```

But how to stop at 50 second? It isn't good solution for me to use timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at `OffsetSampleProvider`. It has `SkipOver` and `Take` properties allowing you to skip over the first 20 seconds and then take the next 30 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, it was useful. The code is as follows:

```
using NAudio.Wave;
using NAudio.Wave.SampleProviders;
...
private AudioFileReader wave = null;
private WaveOut outputSound = null;
...
wave = new NAudio.Wave.AudioFileReader(fileName);
OffsetSampleProvider offsetSampleProvider = new OffsetSampleProvider(wave);
offsetSampleProvider.SkipOver = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeFrom);
offsetSampleProvider.Take = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeTo - timeFrom); 
outputSound = new WaveOut();
outputSound.Init(offsetSampleProvider);
outputSound.Play();
```